# How to make a scroll for vertical nav tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have more then 10 nav items, i want to show 10 nav items and rest will move on scroll , for that i am trying to create top and bottom button (icon) which will scroll for the rest of items top and bottom of the vertical list.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">

     <span class="to-previous getPrevious">
         <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
     </span>

     <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">1</a>
     </li>

     <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">2</a>
     </li>

     <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab">3</a>
     </li>

     <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab">4</a>
     </li>

     <span class="to-next getNext"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>

     <span class="to-next getNext"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>

</ul>
```

I expected output, on click of one of the icons rest items should be visible...
On the above code there are only 4 list items, but these are supposed to be more then 50.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are trying to achieve is bit difficult to understand just by imagining but I thing this Jquery plugin should be helpful.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/custom-scrollbar-scroll-panel.html